# Resource Planning Question

Tags: ms-project, resource-planning

Does anyone know how to plan one resource in Project 2010 when the touch time for that resource for the task such as reviewing something is only 5 hours, but I am obligated to have the object in a review cycle for 5 days?  Review cycles may have multiple reviewers and will never total the 5 days.

Answer (score 0):

Separate out the effort (work) from the cycle time (duration). In the Gantt chart view you can add separate columns for those, and enter 5h for work and 5d for duration.

The scheduling engine calculates based on work and % allocation of the resource. If the resource is allocated at 100% or 1 FTE on that task, the scheduler will front-load the 5h on the first day of the review cycle. If you want to change that, go to the Resource Usage view, double-click on the assignment (italicized task name), and change the Units (% allocation) and Work Contour until you get the result you're looking for.

When I'm leveling a resource in this way I use the Resource Allocation view, which shows the Resource Usage on the top half of the screen and the Levelling Gantt on the bottom. Remember that the line items in italics on any Usage view are assignment objects, not tasks or resources, and they have their own attributes; so changes to duration & dates of assignments may not carry through to the task item.